# Data format for offline apps on iPad?

Tags: tiles, mapnik, mapbox, offline

For an iPAD application (based on WhirlyGlobe) we've two modes: offline and online.

It's a meteorological application so each day around 1600 layers (worldwide) per day are created on the servers. We've a backend service (based on Spark) which is generating mbtiles.

The iPAD loads these layers using a tile web service (online) or just loading the MBTiles (offline).

For the offline we need around 3GB per day and this is quite difficult to maintain for an iOS App.

We're using MBTiles because we use Mapnik for styling the layers. The simbology of the layers are quite specials so we need a really good/flexible render engine.

We've tried to use Mapnik Vector Tiles (MVT) but surprisingly the size of mbtiles of images are quite similar to mbtiles of MVT.

For offline, the max_zoom of the layers is 4.

Should I consider other format of data? Does anybody have an idea about how the size could be reduce?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I would like to see some stats on vector vs raster tile rendering in general, but agreed, you would expect vector to be faster.